# How can I set ListView's scroll in NestedScroll, ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I added my items on the `ListView`.
I can use `NestedScroll's` scroll but I can't show my `listView's` items, I can only show 3 one.

I want to a design like Twitter profile page

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ProfileFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout...>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            ...>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarProfile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `nestedScrolling` of your `listview` :

```
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/listViewProfile"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" \\add this line
     android:scrollbars="vertical">
</ListView>
```